# Deploying a custom build of Dojo

Tags: build, dojo

I'm trying to build `Dojo 1.6.1`.

I ran `C:\somepath\dojo-release-1.6.1-src\dojo-release-1.6.1-src\util\buildscripts>build.bat action=release htmlFiles="C:\path\test.jsp"`

Test.jsp contained a few js files.  One of which contained all the require statements.

Now I have a `release\dojo` folder, but if I put these contents into my original source location, it will break my `test.jsp`'s `<script>` tags.

I found some documentation of the build process: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/build/

I could not find documentation on how to DEPLOY the build.  Is the deploy simply a copy paste but the problem was that my build didn't work properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Dojo custom build is intended to serve as a drop-in replacement for a standard full Dojo distribution as you would include via:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/path/to/dojo/dojo/dojo.js'></script>
```

Typically deployment is simply changing that to:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/path/to/your-custom-dojo/dojo/dojo.js'></script>
```

If your `test.jsp` file does things like `dojo.require()` with inline `<script>` tags, they should continue working correctly.

Comment: The reason mine wasn't compiling properly was poor use of `dojo.require`